How to integrate Federated Learning using Flower framworke in react js /flask web app
I want to create a web application using React.js, Flask, and the Flower framework with Tensorflow  for image classification. I am stuck and would appreciate any tips or resources. Can anyone help me?
I asked GPT and Gemini, but all the answers didn't work for me.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
